# Download files through Wix Bootstrapper\Wix Toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.9

I have some files in server and during installation, those files should be downloaded automatically. I don't want to append those files along with my installer. It should be kept on the server and downloaded during install time only.

Is there any possibility to download the files through wix burn\bootstrapper?

Or Is it possible to download the file using WiX Toolset?

Comment: Hi, how did you solve it? i want to do the same and i do not know how i can do using WiX Toolset installer.